# 'Fake' end of line (EOF)

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, unix, eof

I am decrypting a file that apparently contains end of line prior to the actual end of file and I can't seem to find a solution to it. Does anyone have an idea how to keep it as a byte to be decrypted and continue reading until the next EOF?

EDIT:
I read the file as:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
```

The file itself is encrypted using AES-128 in ECB mode, I haven't managed to read it completely (when reading with 'cat' it also stops after reading 238 characters). I've managed to decrypt the information so far in the file but I've been told that it has a fake EOF and now the decrypted text basically stops in the middle of a sentence

Comment: Can you show the actual data and the code which you used? We might be able to help you better with them

Comment: I'm just going to take a moment to reflect on the fact that you decided to tag the whole field of "computer science" for your question

Comment: Added how I read it, sorry @CoryKramer

Comment: 1. Why do you think that the file is longer than the content shown by cat? 2. I am very confused which of the methods read the file properly and which do not. Can you help me?

Comment: Something like the `od` command can be very useful when you're confused about what exactly a file contains and where it ends.  (If you don't like reading octal or hex, you can use the `-a` flag.)  And if the puzzle is merely how many characters the file contains, there are always `wc -c` and `ls -l`.